# Can't initialize a Two-Dimentional Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store X axis position of mouse and Y axis position of mouse separately inside a two dimentional array and use it later but getting errors.
I am new to arrays and i am trying to initialize a two dimentional array using for loops and instance variables/global variables. The error which i am getting says that "array constants can only be used in initializers". I went through the documentetions and changed the code but not got a solution.

#### Questions and documentations which i read to get a solution

- [Create a 2 dimentional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/creating-two-dimensional-array)
- [Initialize a two dimentional array](http://letmehelpyougeeks.blogspot.in/2009/01/two-dimensional-java.html)
- [Java: Declaring a multidimensional array without specifying the size of the array ( eg. new int[10][] )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896968/java-declaring-a-multidimensional-array-without-specifying-the-size-of-the-arra)
- [casting Object array to Integer array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115230/casting-object-array-to-integer-array-error)
- [Array 2 Dimentional](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D.html)
- [java convert integer to int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/java-convert-integer-to-int-array)

#### My code:

```
package com.selenium;

import java.awt.*;

public class MouseAxis {
  int[][] mouseLocation ;
  int AxisX;
  int AxisY;

public void getAxisXAndY(int x, int y){
    AxisX=x;
    AxisY=y;
} // getAxisXAndY

public void mouseAxisPosition() throws AWTException{
    int x , y;
    PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point point = pointer.getLocation();
    x=(int)point.getX();
    y=(int)point.getY();
    getAxisXAndY(x,y);
} // mouseAxisPosition

public void storeMouseLocation(){
 for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
      for(int j=i; j<=1; j++){
        int[][] temp = new int[j][i];
        temp[j][i]={AxisX,AxisY} ;
        mouseLocation[j][i]=temp[j][i];
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        mouseAxisPosition();
      } // for_2
  } // for_1
 } // storeMouseLocation
} // MouseAxis
```

Comment: Well you never assign a value to `mouseLocation`, so it has the default value of `null`... this wouldn't work with *single*-dimensional arrays either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to store data in the indices.  If you want an array of locations, then you have a few options:

**Have 2 arrays**

```
int lastLocation = 0;
int[] x = new int[10];
int[] y = new int[10];

PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point point = pointer.getLocation();
x[lastLocation] = (int)point.getX();
y[lastLocation] = (int)point.getY();
lastLocation++;
```

Given an index i, you can get the x and y values from the array.

**Create an array of a specialized type**

Just store the whole `Point` object:

```
int lastLocation = 0;
Point[] points = new Point[10];
PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point point = pointer.getLocation();
points[lastLocation] = point;
lastLocaiton++;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, an `int[][]` represents an array of *references* to arrays of integers.  While some languages have a concept of an NxM array of integers, Java does not; the closest it can come would be an array of N references which independently happen to identify distinct M-item arrays of integers.

If one wants to make `MouseLocation` appear to identify an NxM array of integers, one must first initialize it to identify an array of N references to integer arrays, and then initialize *each element* of that array to identify a different array of M integers.  For example, to initialize it to 5x7, one would do something like:

```
mouseLocation = new int[5][];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
  mouseLocation[i] = new int[7];
```

Note that Java does not enforce any requirement that all the inner arrays be distinct, but things will behave strangely if they are not.  For example, if one says:

```
mouseLocation[2] = mouseLocation[3];
```

that may appear initially to copy everything from row 3 to row 2, but it will have another effect as well: any operation on the array identified by `mouseLocation[2]` will also operate on the array identified by `mouseLocation[3]`, since they will be *the same array*.

Arrays of arrays can be tricky in Java; in some cases, it may be simpler to represent an NxM grid using a single array of N*M elements.  The accessing code may be less intuitive (an access to the element at [i,j] would be written as `theArray[i*M+j]`) but the array will behave as a single object, rather than as a group of references to objects which should all distinct.

Comment: -1 because Java provides a syntax for setting up a 2-D array, `new int[5][7]`, contrary to your implication that you have to write the loop yourself.  +1 for the other useful information.

Comment: @ajb: I thought I tried that once and it didn't work; did it always provide that feature?  I can certainly edit the post to correct that detail.  In any case, even if Java provides a syntax equivalent to the loop, it's still important to note that it doesn't create a 5x7 array, but creates an array of five references to seven-element arrays.  Am I remembering right that calling methods like `clone` on such an array will thus generally be pretty useless, since the new array will identify the same five seven-element arrays as the original?

Comment: Yes, I think Java has always had this.  `Arrays.copyOf()` can be used to copy a one-dimensional array, but if the elements are references, they will be the same references.  I don't see a "deep copy" for multi-dimensional arrays either in the JRE or Apache Commons, but someone says they have one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564832/how-do-i-do-a-deep-copy-of-a-2d-array-in-java).