# How can I convert Collection<char[]> to char[][] in java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, char, primitive

I'm trying to speed up an existing implementation of an algorithm in order to parallelize it on the GPU, but to do that all I need to convert all datatypes to primitives.

I have a collection of char-arrays `Collection<char[]>` how can I transform it into an array of char-arrays `char[][]`?

I tried `final char[][] kernelFeatures = (char[][]) features.toArray();`

However, I am getting an error message `java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[C ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [[C are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`.

Comment: `char[][] array = collection.toArray(char[][]::new)`.

Comment: @Slaw I am getting an error `Constructor references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above` which makes absolutely no sense as my java home is set to 13

Comment: @Bossan are you using Intellij? `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S` => `Project` (under `Project Settings`) and under `Project language level` change it to at least `1.8`.

Comment: @Fureeish vscode

Comment: @Bossan Who's giving you the error? The Java compiler or the IDE?

Comment: @Slaw both, the IDE is redlining it and the compiler throws the error when I run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The reason you can't use [`Collection#toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()) and cast the result to `char[][]` is because:

> The returned array's [runtime component type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getComponentType()) is `Object`.

---

## Solutions

### Pre Java 11

You can use [`Collection#toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T[])) which allows to to specify the component type of the array.

```java
Collection<char[]> collection = ...;
char[][] array = collection.toArray(new char[0][]);
```

To understand why you don't need to specify the second dimension, remember that two-dimensional arrays in Java are simply one-dimensional arrays where each element is an array. See these Q&As for more information:

- [Syntax for creating a two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231453/syntax-for-creating-a-two-dimensional-array)
- [Why second dimension is not mandatory in 2d array in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45582174/why-second-dimension-is-not-mandatory-in-2d-array-in-java)

Regarding the use of `0` as the first dimension, note that using `0` is not required; you can use any valid length you want (e.g. `collection.size()`). The reason for using `0`, however, is that it's supposedly more efficient, at least when using an `ArrayList` on HotSpot 8:

- [.toArray(new MyClass[0]) or .toArray(new MyClass[myList.size()])?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174093/toarraynew-myclass0-or-toarraynew-myclassmylist-size)

I'm not sure if it's more efficient in other versions, other JVM implementations, or for other `Collection` implementations.

### Java 11+

If you're using Java 11+ then there's an *alternative* solution: [`Collection#toArray(IntFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(java.util.function.IntFunction)).

```java
Collection<char[]> collection = ...;
char[][] array = collection.toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Which, as a lambda expression, would look like:

```java
Collection<char[] collection = ...;
char[][] array = collection.toArray(i -> new char[i][]);
```

### Manual Copy

Both of the `#toArray` methods ultimately do something similar to:

```java
Collection<char[]> collection = ...;

char[][] array = new char[collection.size()][];
int index = 0;
for (char[] element : collection) {
  array[index++] = element;
}
```

Though you should use one of the `#toArray` methods because that allows the `Collection` implementation to use any optimizations it can. For example, the `ArrayList` class uses the `System#arraycopy` method.

Comment: Thanks, `char[][] array = collection.toArray(new char[0][]);` solved it for me. Could you elaborate on how/why it works and why the char[][] has to have a 0 as a first index?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
  List<char[]> list = List.of(new char[] { '1', '2'
      }, new char[] { '3', '4'
      }, new char[] { '6', '7'
      });
      char[][] array = list.stream().toArray(char[][]::new);
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

or to print out with a for loop

```java
    for (char[] c : array) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
    }
```